# change of coordinates in integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, transformation, change-of-variable

Given a transformation of coordinates

$$
\bar{x} = \frac{x}{x_0}
$$

how do I change the coordinates on the integral:

$$
I_1 = \int_a^b {f(x)}dx\\
$$

And how do I change it if my function is defined as:

$$
I_2(x) = \int_0^x {f(\tau)d\tau}
$$

Integral 1 seems to be straightforward:
$$
x=x_0\ \bar{x}\rightarrow dx=x_0\ d\bar{x}
$$

$$
I_1 = x_0\ \int_c^d {f(x_0\ \bar{x})}d\bar{x} \\
$$

Does integral 2 just change the limits?

$$
I_2(\bar{x}) = \int_0^{x_0\ \bar{x}} {f(\tau)d\tau}
$$

Comment: On (1), it is $x$ that runs from $a$ to $b$. The limits for $\bar x$ are different. (2) is just (1) with the labels changed and $a=0$

Comment: On (1), yes, the limits changes. But on (2), the question wasn't exactly clear. I will edit the question, but what I'm asking is if $I_2$ is a function of $x$, then how do we do the change of coordinates?

Comment: Let me be more explicit: that $x$ in $I_1$ and $\tau$ in $I_2$? Those are dummy variables. The value of $I_1$ depends on $a, b$ and $f$. It does not depend on $x$. You can rewrite $I_1$ as $$I_1 = \int_a^b {f(\tau)}d\tau$$ It is the same integral, and it would be handled the same way under the change of coordinates. Now note that the only difference between $I_1$ and $I_2$ is $a \to 0, b \to x$. Don't let the fact the change of coordinates was explained using the label $x$ fool you. The actual change is not controlled by labels. $x$ plays the same role in $I_2$ as $b$ in $I_1$.

Comment: Yes, yes, I get that. But (1) and (2) are two different things. (1) is change the change of variables in a integral. But on (2), is the change of coordinates of a function. Suppose we define a function of $x$, $f(x)$, as $I_2(x)$, i.e, $f(x)=I_2(x)=\int_0^x{g(\tau) d\tau}$, where $g(\tau)$ is a generic function. How do we change the coordinates of the function $I_2(x)$, given its value is the definite integral of some generic function from $0$ to $x$? Did you understood the difference, or am I confusing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: No (1) and (2) are the exact same thing. Well, almost, because $I_1 = I_1(a,b)$ is a function of *two variables*, while $I_2$ is the same function of only one variable, with other variable set to $0$. Other than that, the label of the surviving variable has been changed, but that is immaterial. $I_2(x) = I_1(0,x)$. Figure out what the new limits on $I_1$ are (all you did in your edit is rename them - so I'm not sure if you understand how to find them in terms of $a$ and $b$ or not). Then replace $b$ in your expression for $I_1$ with $x$, and $a$ with $0$, and you have $I_2(x)$.

Comment: Ah, yes, now I get it. Thanks